# Compare all pending changes instead of one by one in TFS

Tags: tfs

Currently I am using `tf diff` to compare pending changes in WinDiff, which opens one file at a time and the next file is opened only after the previous one is closed.

Since most comparison tools, including WinDiff, supports comparing multiple files, is it possible to compare all pending changes at once? So that I can navigate back and forth as well as view files in the order I want to. I couldn't find a TFS or TFPT command to do so.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WinDiff but most of the diff/merge tools I'm familiar with do not support comparing multiple files explicitly, they support comparing *two directories*.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @EdwardThomson That would work too. The question is not specific to WinDiff, instead, it is more about TFS commands and tools.

Answer (score 1):

This VS extension allows you to compare many files in separate or one continuous file. 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d8d61cc9-6660-41af-b8d0-0f8403b4b39c